# Does Ember support localization like SC 1.x

Tags: ember.js

We were able to easily localize SC app with the strings table and sc-build did a good job of building out the different lang directories with the right localized files. Does Ember provide these?

thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly the same as SC 1.x, but yes there is localization in Ember.

You'll first need to define your localized strings to Ember.STRINGS:

```
Ember.STRINGS = {
  '_save': 'Save',
  '_ok': 'OK',
  '_apply': 'Apply',
  '_cancel': 'Cancel',
  '_close': 'Close',
  '_refresh': 'Refresh'
}
```

Then you can localize any string by adding `.loc()` to a string to localize it:

```
`_close`.loc() outputs "Close"
```

You can read the source [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/string.js#L65-101) in ember-runtime and the tests [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/tests/system/string/loc_test.js).

Comment: No. Most people use either rake-pipeline or BPM as their build tools for Ember projects.

Comment: As a tangential note, rake-pipeline and BPM are both deprecated. Focus is now on ember-app-kit.

Answer (score 4):

ZenDesk has a nice internationalization library, currently named sproutcore-i18n that I'd recommend. I expect they'll be changing the name to ember-i18n in the near future.

https://github.com/zendesk/sproutcore-i18n