# I18n in EmberJS (routing and in general)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, routes, ember.js, ember-router

Does EmberJS support translated routes for internationalized apps? Or does it at least make it easy to extend it to support i18n routes? Anybody with experience with this?

E.g. can the route string be somehow set dynamically from locale files? Also it would be cool when using Ember with Rails routing would not have to be specified twice... is that so?

I'm new to Ember (currently evaluating js frameworks) but I assume in general with Rails one would simply specify very basic routes from within Rails and the rest in Ember? So there wouldn't be much duplication? Wonder if locale files from Rails could be used to lookup route translations.

As a more general question: does Ember has any support for I18n already?

Comment: Relevant question about I18n: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762456/does-ember-support-localization-like-sc-1-x

Comment: Why would you want to create internationalized routes? I can't think of an use case, so I'm just wondering.

Comment: Well, in an internationalized app with "pretty", readable urls. 
Like e.g. /article/a-great-article  would become in german: /artikel/ein-toller-artikel

Comment: Basically you would want this for seo and a native language app feeling for users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve internationalized routes by reopening `Ember.Route` and setting the localized route when it is initialized, see an example here http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/wQXvb/.

You have to make sure that the `Ember.STRINGS` is defined *before* your router is initialized. The String lookup itself can be done by the `loc` method, as mentioned by **sly7_7**.

```js
Ember.STRINGS = {
    '/all': '/alle',
    '/home/:id': '/zuhause/:id'
};

Ember.Route.reopen({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        var route = this.get('route');
        if (route) this.set('route', route.loc());
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you proceed if you want routes translated into german or into french ?

Comment: perhaps, or with client side (browser ?) language detection at initialization time

Answer (score 4):

There is an ember-i18n project: https://github.com/zendesk/ember-i18n

It'll help you with your strings, but there isn't a solution for dealing with translated URLs currently.

You can use any JS routing library with Ember. There's a pretty simple `Ember.Location` protocol for integrating your own routing library with `Ember.Router`.

Comment: Thanks, I marked pangratz answer as the accepted answer as my question was slightly more about routing. Would have accepted yours too if possible. Anyone any idea about the third part of my question? ;-) Which is about integration of Ember routes and I18n with a Rails backend.

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer for the general question can be found here:

http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.String&method=.loc&src=false

I think this is not a complete i18n support, and there is no one built in emberjs.

Comment: What's your definition of "complete"?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Wonder if the loc function can be used in routing path definitions.

Comment: @Tass by complete I mean for example multi language support. Perhaps it exists, but I don't know how to do this. For example, I want to translate either into french or german.

Comment: yes, i18n is not complete with one language only, the whole point of i18n is having the app display in multiple languages, e.g. user switchable ;-)