# emberjs router set language of site

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

How can i set `lang` from `setEN` and read from `about`?

Is it good way to choose language on site? Maybe emberjs give some other method for that?

I want change `router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('about');` to load `connectOutlet('about-' + lang )`. In that way i will load `about-pl` or `about-en` depende on what language user choose.

This situation force to reload page after change language. How can I do this? Because when user is in "#/about" and choose new language page should reload to load `about-language`.

```js
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
    enableLogging: true,
    location: 'hash',
    lang: 'pl',

    root: Em.Route.extend({
        // EVENTS
        setPL: function () {
            this.set('lang', 'pl');
        },
        setEN: function () {
            this.set('lang', 'en');
        },

        gotoAbout: Ember.Route.transitionTo('about'),
        gotoProjects: Ember.Route.transitionTo('projects'),
        gotoTechnology: Ember.Route.transitionTo('technology'),
        gotoContact: Ember.Route.transitionTo('contact'),

        index: Em.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('navbar', 'navbar');
            },

            // STATES
            about: Em.Route.extend({
                route: '/',
                connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
                    console.log( router.get('lang') );
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('about');
                }
            }),
```

In other way I can use language as part of path, example: `#/en/about`.
But there is a problem how to change `#/about` to `#/en/about`, `#/contact` to `#/en/contact` and other way round. And with more complicated path `#/projects/12`

Comment: Not sure how much this will help but perhaps see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080435/i18n-in-emberjs-routing-and-in-general

Comment: Thx but this is not exatly what i need. For me easier is prepere other template with name `about-pl`, `about-en` etc.

It`s a really small site with not many text.